# How can we create a "Node" type fild in a Node class?

Tags: java

Stack implementation.
How can we create a "Node" type fild in a Node class??
How can variable "first" of type "Node" contain fild of type "Node"?
Thank You for help

```
public class Stack 
{
private Node first = null;

private class Node
{
    String item;
    Node next;
}

public boolean isEmpty()
{
    return first == null;
}

public void push(String item)
{
    Node oldFirst = first;
    first = new Node();
    first.item = item;
    first.next = oldFirst;  
}

public String pop()
{
    String item = first.item;
    first = first.next;
    return item;
}
```

}

Comment: It's entirely unclear why you think this *wouldn't* work. I suspect you should make `Node` a static nested class though...

Comment: I don't understand the question. How - you have the code there, right?

Comment: the code works, but i don't get the principle

Comment: Are you asking why a class can have a property with the same type than the class? Why would that be a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java handles objects by reference (or pointer).

```
class Node {
     String value;
     Node next;
}
```

Given an instance of this class, its body requires 8 bytes memory (on a 32-bit machine). The first 4 byte store a pointer to the string, the next 4 byte point to another `Node` object (or null).

Answer (score 1):

`Node` is a recursive data structure. Imagine you have a list. A list can be empty or has a first element and a rest, where the rest is also a list.

In your `Stack` class you hold a reference of the first `Node` instance. And this first instance consists of a String value and a reference to the next `Node` instance. At first, it is not easy to understand that a class can have a field of the same class. But this is a fundamental prinicple. I.e. you have a class Person. One Person instance can have associations to other Person instances. Like `father`. Then it is natural that you include a field `father` in class Person. And the type of `father` is Person. It's no magic. It's only the way to model associations between class instances. The only special thing here is, that these are associations between the same class and not between two different classes.